# Json file in java can't handle escape sign?

Tags: javascript, json, jackson

I am reading the following json-file in js but in the End i got too many quotes:

```
{"val":["\"scene\"","\"roof\""]}
```

My output is

```
 val[0] -> '"scene"'
```

Is it possible to remove those quotes or the escape signs directly from the json object.

```
function getKeyJson(path)
    {
        ($.ajax({
            url: path,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                jsonObj = data;
            }
        }));
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why that json file is constructed that way? are you constructing it, or getting from some external?

Comment: external, from a java-based tool

Comment: I wonder why it's been constructed that way, if it is like this {"val":["scene","roof"]}, it should work I believe.

Comment: True, but my json is valid and wants to be parsed^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So don't worry i handle it like this in java:

```
 String a = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonMap);
 a = a.replace("\\\"", "");
System.out.println(a);
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(a);
mapper.writeValue(new File(path), node);
```